# Addressing malicious crawlers with page overload techniques

Tags: web-crawler, bandwidth

Back in the old days, when I was a smart-aleck kid, my office had 12 sheets of black construction paper beside the fax machine. When some loose-witted tool sent us a spam fax, we would punch up the return fax number and send back 12 pages of blackness. The idea was that they should know that if they wanted to tell us about their new cleaning product, it would cost them 12 pages of thermal paper each time. It worked!

Jump ahead 30 years. I am finding my bandwidth being sucked up by malicious web crawlers who are likely up to no good (ie. 103.224.248.167).

I thought I would ask the community here if there is a 2015 version of 12 sheets of black paper. What is the best way to deal with this assault?

Comment: Heh, would like to know that, too. In this form, it's not on topic on Stack Overflow, though, I'm afraid.

Comment: Should I just say, "What is the best way to deal with malicious Web crawlers?" Respectfully, what do you need to know?